# How to solve $y''+y'/x+f(x)y=0$ with $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=1$?

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve this particular ode 
$y''+y'/x+f(x)y=0$ with $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=1$.

I have tried `DSolve` by taking $f(x)=16+8x^4-24x^2$.

But the output remains same as input for reasons not understood

Comment: Add your try to the question.

Comment: $y(x)=0$ is solution.

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer?

Comment: @MMM Yes. Trying Numerical approach.

Comment: @TilakMallikarjun Check my edited response

Answer (score 3):

> But the output remains same as input for reasons not understood

Short answer, the problem is with your initial conditions, as for as the output is concern.

***Mathematica***

```
f = 16 + 8*x^4 - 24*x^2;
ode = y''[x] + y'[x]/x + f*y[x] == 0
```

If we try to solve the ode without the conditions we get an output in terms of `DifferentialRoot`, which mean `holonomic function`. But the thing to remember is that `DSolve` is unable to find a solution to the ode.

```
First @@ DSolve[ode, y, x]
```

[image: Blockquote]

The initial conditions is causing the situation `1/0` to avoid this I will choose `10^(-4)` instead of `0` as a starting point for `x`.

```
sol = First@@DSolve[{ode, y[10^(-4)] == 0, y'[10^(-4)] == 1}, y, x]
```

[image]

```
Plot[y[x] /. sol, {x, 10^(-4), 10}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

You can use `NDSolve` to find numerical solution,

```
sol = First@NDSolve[{ode, y[10^(-4)] == 0, y'[10^(-4)] == 1}, y, {x, 10^(-4), 10}]
Plot[y[x] /. sol, {x, 10^(-4), 10}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True,   PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

**Maple**

Maple is also unable to find a solution.

```
restart:with(plots):
f:= 16 + 8*x^4 - 24*x^2:
ode:= diff(y(x),x$2) + diff(y(x),x$1)/x + f*y(x)=0:
dsolve(ode);
```

[image]

> DESol is a data structure to represent the solution of a differential equation.

Comment: With boundary conditions defined more closer to origin say 1e-16, I get a slightly different solution, with different roots

Comment: @TilakMallikarjun The ode has this term `1/x`, the more you get closer to `0` it will take you closer to `1/0`.